# Why can I not add a second boolean?

Tags: boolean-modifier

I would like to add another boolean, but when I try nothing happens to my main object.

As you can see in the picture below, I want to create a mesh that has the inner circle standing, because I want to extrude that a bit.
However, I am not able to use boolean on the outer circle.

Or is it best to create a whole new mesh from this?

I will include the file: [image]

[image]

Comment: It's a bit difficult to see exactly what you're trying to do from that image. Doesn't it show correctly if you hide the modifier (Water boolean.004) in the outliner?